# Dedication Punctuation - include a period?

Tags: punctuation

For the dedication of my upcoming book, I have written

> For my child.

Do you think that period should be there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all based on the author, both ways work.  If you like the feel of a completed sentence, punctuation is your friend!  If you would rather prefer the dedication to be more like a headline, skip the periods.

Answer (score 0):

sure, why not? just don't do the crazy poetry thing and hold the period until the blank page after the About the Author blurb.

More seriously, it's a purely aesthetic choice. Use it, leave it out, doesn't matter.